# Delimiters to be used while creating hive table

Tags: hive, hdfs, nvarchar

Imported logs Table from SQL server to HDFS in compressed format(.gz).

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ServerName:1433/Test" --username sa --password root --table log --target-dir hdfs://localhost:50071/TestMain --fields-terminated-by "¤" --hive-import --create-hive-table --compress --split-by Logid
```

Created a external table in hive on top of this data.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestMain(LogMessage varchar(2000))
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "¤" 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:50071/TestMain';
```

Those logs have a column of datatype `nvarchar(max)` in SQL. Which should be the corresponding datatype to be used in Hive?

I tried using the `string` datatype in hive but facing the below issue:
While running the select query in hive, I can see only first few words of the field. I can’t see the whole column value.

Example:
That field have the below value in SQL:

```
Message: Procedure or function 'XYZ' expects parameter '@ABC', which was not supplied.
Stacktrace:    This has whole 5 lines error stack trace.
```

Value visible while querying in Hive:

```
Procedure or function 'XYZ' expects parameter '@ABC', which was not supplied.
```

It seems to be some issue with the field and line delimiter.
Hive supports only new line as the line delimiter. I think this is causing the issue.

Kindly suggest a solution or better way to query this data in HDFS.

Comment: one option is to drop delimiters when importing data with Sqoop using `--hive-drop-import-delims` and `--hive-delims-replacement`

Comment: I used this option --hive-delims-replacement while importing the data in HDFS. Then, I was able to query the data.

Thanks @VamsiPrabhala